# In Gattaca, why did nobody figure out the relationship between the unregistered in-valid and the detective hunting him?

Tags: movie, gattaca

After the discovery of in-valid DNA at the crime scene, the police analyze it and pull up the profile (including biography) of

> Vincent Freeman.

Later in the movie it is revealed that one of the detectives on the case is

> Anton Freeman, Vincent's brother.

Obviously he knew this all along, but how did the other detective (and everybody else) working on the case miss it?

Comment: great question, I've asked that myself several times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The other detective (Hugo) figures it out in a deleted scene:

> Hugo: It seems you and the eyelash share something in common. Not much, but enough to establish a rather damaging connection. I should have turned you in, sir, I really should, but I guess pity's clouded my better judgment. One of my many, many failings. That's probably why I'm only a detective second class.

This also strongly implies that Hugo has been passed over for promotion because he is a natural. Depending on how you interpret the scene he may even want to blackmail Anton to get that promotion.

Answer (score 8):

As I recall there are no overt indications, but from the point of view of most Valids the Invalids are *not really people* at all, so it may not occur to them that the highly competent detective they know could possibly be related to a non-person at all.

We can presume that Antonio doesn't talk about his brother the Invalid, and the name is not an uncommon one.

Antonio presumably keeps his mouth shut because being known to be related to a Invalid won't do him any good, and stays on the case in order to keep his options open. Maybe even to try to give Vincent a break some how.

Comment: This is correct, Antonio keeps the information to himself and no one else would think that Antonio would be related to what amounts to human garbage in their eyes.

Comment: The only part I don't buy is that nobody else could figure it out on their own by just reading the profile of the guy they are looking for. "Hey, it says here he's got a brother who's a cop! And he looks just like you and has the same name, but for some reason you didn't mention it. Must be coincidence."

Comment: @AlistairBuxton Well yeah, that's kinda the point :) - if you're used to everything coming easy, you won't put in the effort to be truly great. That's why the detective swam back, instead of forging on like his brother.

Comment: I always figured the older but lower-rank detective was a natural who was grandfathered in - they couldn't fire him, instead they just stopped promoting him, which is why he is "junior" to the much younger Anton. His apparent hate for in-valids can then be explained by him blaming "troublemaking in-valids" for his current situation. That's pure speculation of course but it makes these "well, they have it so easy, they are just lazy" explanations not sit right with me, since he doesn't appear to have it particularly easy. Anyway, I forgot about this question for ages, so accepting your answer.

Comment: The detective's name is Anton.  His _father_ was Antonio.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, Vincent wasn't unregistered *per se*.  As Vincent Freeman, he *was* registered legally.  He had worked at GATTACA as a janitor, so finding his DNA there wasn't entirely unusual.

But I realize that isn't your question.  I agree with dmckee that there are probably multiple reasons why people never put two and two together.

- We know that Vincent isn't in touch with his family.  There's no evidence to suggest that they exchange Christmas cards, for example.  Additionally, if he's living as Jerome then it would look suspicious if he's hanging out with a family Jerome's not associated with.
- Given how in-valids are treated, it's reasonable to assume that having one in your family (if you are a valid) is sort of like having that uncle that's in and out of prison all the time.  No one really talks about them.
- Vincent doesn't really look that much like Anton.  He wears glasses, he's shorter.
- How much background information do they really keep on in-valids--especially one who hasn't been in trouble with the law and has more or less kept himself off the radar?
- Even if someone *did* bother to look, they would probably think, "No way does he have an in-valid brother!"

Comment: Anton tells Vincent 'Our parents both died thinking they had outlived you', so no family to contact (and the fact that Vincent didn't know that suggests he had not contacted them since he had left home.  Also, while Vincent's DNA is in the police system, he might not be 'registered'.  When Anton is frustrated with the locations of Hugo's searches, he says 'He's an In-Valid who's been clever enough to go unregistered all these years, you think he's going to lie down for us now?'

Comment: Either Vincent just disappeared from the system at some point (stopped registering with the government), or Anton [is lying](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15642/in-gattaca-why-did-nobody-figure-out-the-relationship-between-the-unregistered#comment785929_18588)

Answer (score 4):

### Anton is restricting access to this information

As the lead detective in charge of the investigation, Anton is deliberately making sure that no one makes this connection.

At one point junior detective Hugo asks Anton, 'What do we know about the eyelash, sir? Any family?' and Anton responds, 'I've already run the analysis - no living relatives.' [quotes approximate, from memory]. Anton is of course lying about Vincent not having relatives, so having 'already run' the analysis and explicitly shutting down Hugo's line of questioning implies that he is making sure others do not have access to this information.  If he can control what the team working for him has access to, no one outside his team would have access to the names of suspects or the identities of samples.

Anton's control of the investigation is shown in a physical metaphor at the club, when another detective tries to collect the pill case on the table.  Anton grabs his arm forcefully, preventing the detective from picking up the case, and then he takes it himself.  These pills are Irene's heart medicine, but Anton actually thinks that it is Vincent's, since Vincent has a heart condition.  Anton doesn't want to let anyone on the team collect any evidence about Vincent if he can help it.

In a later scene Anton is flipping back and forth between pictures of old Vincent and new Vincent-as-Jerome on a computer screen; he by now suspects that Vincent is using the identity of Jerome (but probably doesn't believe that he is physically impersonating him at work; perhaps it is just fraud or identity theft).  Hugo walks in on him and says 'Isn't that the man from last night?' (when Vincent fled from them at the club) and Anton immediately shuts off the display and says 'He's no one'. It is clear that as much as he is trying to find Vincent, Anton is also making sure that no one else finds Vincent (or makes the connection to him), and he is deliberately blocking his team's access to crucial information.

Then, when Anton agrees to meet Vincent at Gattaca, he comes alone and tells Vincent that 'You're in a lot of trouble; I can get you out of here."  Clearly he has not told his team about this meeting (they are all off celebrating the confession of the Director) and his goal is to remove Vincent from Gattaca without anyone on the police force understanding the connection between them.

Finally, in the deleted scene described by [ssss](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/50631/47264), Hugo confronts Anton and explains that he has figured out the connection *despite* Anton's attempts to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

Also, Anton was the head detective on the scene, he was the Valid, he obviously controlled the direction of the investigation, he might have been able to restrict access to those kinds of records.

Comment: Although that's true, there doesn't seem to be any indication that this is actually the case

Comment: @Valorum At one point Hugo asks Anton, 'What do we know about the eyelash, sir?  Any family?' and Anton responds, 'I've already run the analysis - no living relatives.' [quotes approximate, from memory].  Anton is explicitly lying about Vincent not having relatives, so having 'already run' the analysis and explicitly shutting down Hugo's line of questioning I think it is implied that he is making sure others do not have access to this information.

Comment: @Valorum There is also the scene where he is flipping back and forth between pictures of old Vincent and new Vincent-as-Jerome on a computer screen.  Hugo walks in on him and says 'Isn't that the man from last night?' (when Vincent fled them from the club) and Anton immediately shuts of the display and says 'He's no one'.  I think it is clear that as much as he is trying to find Vincent, Anton is also making sure that no one else finds Vincent (or makes the connection to him).